# Calcular días transcurridos hasta la fecha actual

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito calcular los días transcurridos desde una fecha pasada que seleccione hasta la fecha actual(sistema) en formato yyyy-mm-dd y mostrarlo en un input text, hasta ahora tengo el siguiente el código.

```
<script>
function restar(){
var hoy = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
var fecha1 = moment(document.getElementById('FECHA_ENT').value);
var fecha2 = moment(document.getElementById(hoy).value);

getElementById('MORA').value = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days');
}
</script>
```

También tengo un input text con id=MORA donde espero obtener el resultado y un button con el evento onclick para llamar la función.

Comment: Ya estuve probando esa solución y no me funciono por que necesito otro formato

Comment: El formato no debería importar; Internamente, una fecha es una fecha. A menos que, ¿estás usando Moment.js u otra biblioteca para gestionar las fechas? (Como parece que es el caso). Eso haría la pregunta diferente a la otra, pero deberías indicarlo claramente en tu publicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a usar moments.js asegurate de pasarle a la funcion moment como primer parametro una fecha y como segundo parametro el formato que tiene tu fecha, en este caso YYYY-MM-DD.

Suponiendo que tu variable hoy recibe el id de un input y ese input tiene la fecha con el mismo formato YYYY-MM-DD el código quedaría así:

```js
var hoy = "FECHA_HOY"; 
var fecha1 = moment(document.getElementById('FECHA_ENT').value, "YYYY-MM-DD"); //El segundo parametro es el formato de tu fecha
var fecha2 = moment(document.getElementById(hoy).value, "YYYY-MM-DD");//Mismo caso que fecha1

document.getElementById('MORA').value = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="FECHA_ENT" value="2017-06-2" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="FECHA_HOY" value="2017-06-22" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="MORA" />
```

Pero si simplemente quieres comprobar con la fecha del sistema, quedaría asi:

```js
var hoy = Date.now(); //Fecha de hoy 
var fecha1 = moment(document.getElementById('FECHA_ENT').value, "YYYY-MM-DD"); //El segundo parametro es el formato de tu fecha ya que es un string
var fecha2 = moment(hoy);//Recibe directamente la fecha y no hay que pasarle el formato como segundo parametro ya que es un Date

document.getElementById('MORA').value = fecha2.diff(fecha1, 'days');
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="FECHA_ENT" value="2017-06-2" /><br/>
<input type="text" id="MORA" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono de 10!!! pdt: vote pero todavia no me registra las calificaciones

Comment: @AnderssonViverosMartinez si la pregunta resolvió sus dudas no olvide marcar como aceptada.

Comment: Cita comentario propio, de arriba:  
"Muchas gracias, me funciono de 10!!! pdt: vote(califique, acepte...) pero todavía no me registra las calificaciones – Andersson Viveros Martinez hace 6 horas" No puedo todavía marcar como aceptada, soy nuevo...